# What is the proper way to update attribute value in started Spring WebSession?

Tags: spring, spring-session, spring-webflux

I have `SpringBoot 2.0.0.M7` project where I am using `WebSession` with `Redis` (`org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis:2.0.0.RELEASE`).

I have a WebFlux route which supposed to do redirect to eBay with the eBay session id. Every time user is visiting that route I need to request different session id from eBay API and include it into the redirect URL. Later, eBay will redirect user back to my application where I need that session id to request token.

During testing I saw that that value of the session attribute (in my case it's `ebay_session_id`) can't be replaced with the new value when browser still have a cookie with the existing session ID. In the route where I am requesting again `ebay_session_id` I am getting old value and not the new one.

The code which store SessionID is following:

```
return ebayApiReactiveWrapper
        .getSessionId(apiContext)
        .flatMap(sessionId ->
            request
                .session()
                .map(webSession -> {
                    webSession
                        .getAttributes()
                        .put("ebay_session_id", sessionId);

                    return sessionId;
                })
        )
        .flatMap(sessionId -> {
            final UriBuilder uriBuilder = uriBuilderFactory.uriString(
                ebayApiSettings.getSignInUrl()
            );

            uriBuilder.queryParam("runame", ebaySettings.getRuName());
            uriBuilder.queryParam("SessID", sessionId);

            return ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(redirectUri).build();
        });
```

I tried to add `webSession.save()` after `put` method but it doesn't help.

What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

Some new details about what is happening with the session data in Redis. When session is created (empty Redis) the data looks like that:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hkeys "spring:session:sessions:cbbf8000-6ce8-4238-a427-9aab37d2702b"
1) "lastAccessedTime"
2) "maxInactiveInterval"
3) "creationTime"
4) "sessionAttr:ebay_session_id"
```

When I visit same route second time (session cookie still exists and the session data is still in Redis) the data is changing:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hkeys "spring:session:sessions:cbbf8000-6ce8-4238-a427-9aab37d2702b"
1) "sessionAttr:ebay_session_id"
```

Through, `sessionAttr:ebay_session_id` still contains value from the first request.

The worst thing is that such structure cause `NullPointerException` when another route is trying to get session data. Looks like it expecting other 3 fields to be presented and fails when it's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like not many people faced such issue. I found my solution to solve it.

I saw that session will not be updated if the attribute set of the session is not changed. So I am adding a new attribute every time I need to update session value. My first `flatMap` from the question code is changed the following way:

```
.flatMap(sessionId ->
    request
        .session()
        .map(webSession -> {
            // we need to check if session already started before applying "hack"
            if (webSession.isStarted()) {
                // "hack"
                final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yMdkmsn");
                webSession
                    .getAttributes()
                    .put(LocalDateTime.now().format(dateTimeFormatter),"1");
            }

            webSession
                .getAttributes()
                .put("ebay_session_id", sessionId);

            return sessionId;
        })
)
```

When new attribute is added session considered as changed and will be updated in redis.

Answer (score 0):

I faced that problem and used almost the same hack, but just by updating a primitive typed session attribute.

For example:

```
webSession.getAttributes().put("userContext", userContext);

webSession.getAttributes().put("lastContextUpdateTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This avoids to add a new attribute for each session update, but triggers the mutable object update in Redis too.